# Errors deploying Django on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, mariadb

I have 2 problems

1. Before I didn't upload my model to the DB (MariaDB)

[error load model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF7FP.jpg)

2. Now it gives me an error in the configuration DB

   Before I used this configuration

```py
       import dj_database_url
       from decouple import config
       
       DATABASES = {
               'default': dj_database_url.config(
                   default=config('JAWSDB_MARIA_URL')
               )
       }
```

Now the documentation shows another [config Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python) but for both it shows me the same error

[enter load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WM4N.png)

Comment: Please copy the error message and paste it into your post, verbatim but for data security concerns. Block quote welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
    DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

what about whitenoise !!!

```
pip install whitenoise
```

her  setup by setup  about Heroku deployment if you need :

https://github.com/salah-cpu/Cmd_Git/blob/master/deploying_on_Heroku

Comment: of course I have whitenoise installed and using the config that you propose or the one in the documentation gives me this error

NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined

even so thanks for the input

Comment: cheek GitHub it's very helpful  : https://github.com/salah-cpu/Cmd_Git/blob/master/deploying_on_Heroku